# how to pause timer or freeze it and resume -> javascript

Tags: javascript, timer

I am doing a little app in javascript that has some timers around. At some point I need to change the variables that a single timer is using during runtime.

I tried a coiple of times just changing the variable (incrementing it, for instance in 10 units) still the timer will have a weird behavior. So I figured out that the timer must be stopped first, change the variable and after that resume it (but still dunno this is possible).

What I want to ask is: there is any way to pause a timer function and then resume it?

EDIT: the variables are not local for the timer (they are global)

Comment: Please show your code. If the variable is global then it should work correctly. The function you pass to `setTimeout` does not get its own copy of the variable.

Comment: The timer doesn't have to be stopped in order to be able to change the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var t1;
t1 =setTimeout("dosomethig",1000) //1000 = 1 sec

clearTimeout(t1); // to release timeout
```

Comment: The t1 is a timer that I am using? Or is another variable that make timers pause?

Comment: t1 is the variable with stores the delay, and use `clearTimeout(t1)`, if you want to release the delay

Comment: @John: Better you post the code you use or provide a demo. As @Sime and I said, you don't have to stop the timer to change the variable.